# Subdomains as subfolders with requests using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to do my subdomains working with subdirectories without redirection. 
I write this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysubdomain\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/mysubdomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/mysubdomain/$1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

It works good with `mysubdomain.site.com`, but all files inside directory not working. For example `mysubdomain.site.com/robots.txt` open `site.com/robots.txt` not `site.com/cities/subdomain/robots.txt` (**that what I want**)

Can you help with explanation?

My current `.htaccess` is:

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  #php_value display_errors 1
  #php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
  #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com [R=301,L] 

  # sub-domain redirect
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/barnaul/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/barnaul/$1 [L,QSA]
  # sub-domain redirect

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /cities/sms-sending-samara.php http://sub.example.com
Redirect 301 /information/sms_directing.php http://example.com/#sms_directing
Redirect 301 /sitemap_000.xml http://example.com/sitemap.xml
Redirect 301 /information/information.php http://example.com/information/
Redirect 301 /help/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%201%D0%A1%20v8.2.pdf http://example.com/api/modul_1c.php
Redirect 301 /help/Модуль%201С%20v8.2.pdf http://example.com/api/modul_1c.php
Redirect 301 /api/modul.php http://example.com/api/modul_1c.php
Redirect 301 /help/HTTP.pdf http://example.com/api/prot_http.php
Redirect 301 /help/SMPP.pdf http://example.com/api/prot_smpp.php
Redirect 301 /help/SMTP.pdf http://example.com/api/prot_smtp.php
Redirect 301 /help/SOAP.pdf http://example.com/api/prot_soap.php
Redirect 301 /help/XML.pdf http://example.com/api/prot_xml.php
Redirect 301 /API/prot_http.php http://example.com/api/prot_http.php
Redirect 301 /API/prot_smpp.php http://example.com/api/prot_smpp.php
Redirect 301 /API/prot_smtp.php http://example.com/api/prot_smtp.php
Redirect 301 /API/prot_soap.php http://example.com/api/prot_soap.php
Redirect 301 /API/prot_xml.php http://example.com/api/prot_xml.php
Redirect 301 /rassilka_sms_internet.html http://example.com/rassilka_sms_cherez_internet.html
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka_cherez_internet_01.html http://example.com/rassilka_sms_cherez_internet.html
Redirect 301 /internet_rassilka_sms.html http://example.com/rassilka_sms_cherez_internet.html
Redirect 301 /sms_uvedomlenie_2.html http://example.com/sms_uvedomlenie.html
Redirect 301 /sms_uslugi_2.html http://example.com/sms_uslugi.html
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka_reklamy_01.html http://example.com/sms_rassilka_reklamy.html
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka_03.html http://example.com
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka.html  http://example.com
Redirect 301 /rassilka_sms_02.html  http://example.com
Redirect 301 /rassilki_sms_01.html  http://example.com
Redirect 301 /sms_reklama.html  http://example.com/information/reklama.php
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka_deshevo.html  http://example.com/rassilka_sms_deshego.html
Redirect 301 /sms_rassilka_deshevo01.html http://example.com/rassilka_sms_deshego.html
Redirect 301 /rassilka_sms_internet.html http://example.com/rassilka_sms_cherez_internet.html
Redirect 301 /programma_cmc.html http://example.com/programma_sms.html
Redirect 301 /korporativnye_sms.htm http://example.com/korporativnye_sms.html
Redirect 301 /information/sector/index.php http://example.com/reshenia/
Redirect 301 /massovaya_rassilka_sms.html  http://example.com
Redirect 301 /API/ http://example.com/api/
Redirect 301 /API http://example.com/api/
Redirect 301 /sms_trafik.htm http://example.com/smstrafik.html
Redirect 301 /sms_shluz.htm http://example.com/smsshluz.html
Redirect 301 /sms_trafik.html http://example.com/smstrafik.html
Redirect 301 /sms_shluz.html http://example.com/smsshluz.html
Redirect 301 /information/sms_reklama.php http://example.com/information/reklama.php
Redirect 301 /rassilka_ http://example.com
Redirect 301 /information/ackciya.php http://example.com/information/post_akciya.php
Redirect 301 /information/akciya.php http://example.com/information/post_akciya.php
Redirect 301 /information/sector/gov/ http://example.com/reshenia/gosstruktury/
Redirect 301 /information/sector/ http://example.com/reshenia/
Redirect 301 /information/MMS_directing.php http://example.com
Redirect 301 /information/WAP_directing.php http://example.com
Redirect 301 /information/voice_directing.php http://example.com
Redirect 301 /mobilny_marketing.html http://example.com/mobilnymarketing.html
Redirect 301 /cities/sms-sending-belgorod.php http://sub.example.com
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
```

Comment: Are you sure its opening the root `robots.txt` file and not that the one inside the sub domain folder is just equal the one at the root? Your rule looks OK to me the only thing I see wrong is that you're using `$1` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` which technically speaking would generate a internal URL like this `/cities/mysubdomain/robots.txt/robots.txt` and that you're not using `[NC]` at your second condition so it will only do exact match but that would be only affect if you access the folder directly which is no the case I assume.

Comment: @Prix yes, it's open root file =( I've added [NC] to second line and remove {REQUEST_URI} from third - but nothing changed( Also try to add QSA to third

Comment: post your full `.htaccess` file as it might be some ordering issue as well.

Comment: @Prix http://pastebin.com/Sw5A90DU (starts at 19)

Comment: Does it work if you put your rules from `# sub-domain redirect` right after `RewriteBase /` and change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/barnaul/$1 [L,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^ /cities/barnaul%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Prix do this - but nothing changed( http://sms-rassilka-reklama-barnaul.mirsms.ru/robots.txt stil not equals http://mirsms.ru/cities/barnaul/robots.txt

Comment: besides the above mentioned changes add this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?sub\.example\.com$ [NC]` below this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$` and try again. If that does not work then all I can think of is that either the sub domain root folder is not the same of the main domain or you have a secondary `.htaccess` file that is breaking the rules of the main file.

Comment: @Prix the problem was even stranger - it works for all other files (for example: robots2.txt, somefiles.php), BUT not working with robots.txt filename !!! I try to remove all other rules but it's also not work http://pastebin.com/DUmaqVHW Do you have any idea why only this files not open in subdirectory? May be It's a hosting setted? (filepermission I make 777)

Comment: Problem solved! thx! txt files are working under nginx, others - under apache